# How does the oxygenator in The Martian split CO2 to make O2?

Tags: the-martian

In the book, The Martian, I know that the oxygenator cools the air in the hab to separate out the gases.  Then it somehow splits CO2 to get oxygen.  What mechanism does it use to split the CO2?

Comment: related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104502/how-did-mark-watney-manufacture-oxygen-in-the-martian/104503#104503

Comment: FWIW, NASA is planning on fielding one of these to Mars in 2020. http://gizmodo.com/nasa-will-make-oxygen-from-co2-on-the-surface-of-mars-1614018168

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the page 231 of the book:

> It heats CO<sub>2</sub> to 900°C, then passes it over a zirconia electrolysis cell to yank the carbon atoms off.

Thanks Sean Duggan for pointing me to NASA's 2020 Mars mission tech, which includes [MOXIE](http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/atoms/files/fs_moxie_150908.pdf), an experiment in doing the same thing.  It works via:

> MOXIE uses a solid oxide electrolysis (SOXE) stack developed by Ceramatec, Inc. for converting CO<sub>2</sub> to O<sub>2</sub>. Its working elements are stacked scandia
>   stabilized zirconia (ScSZ) electrolyte supported cells with thin screen printed electrodes that are coated with a catalytic cath­ode on one side and an anode on the other.

Comment: The next question is whether that would actually work. But that's a question for another site.

Comment: @Kevin Tada.  The answer's yes.

Comment: with enough energy, you can rearrange molecules as you like.

Comment: What does it do with the carbon?

Comment: @Xantec It's never mentioned in the book. Looking at the real-life NASA experiment, it is actually stripping off an Oxygen atom from CO2. Then it vents CO and O2.

Comment: @SJuan76 - I think CO can be used to make [syngas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syngas).  Keen, thanks for reminding me of Ceramatec, since now I remember reading about their products.  It's all coming back now.  :)

Comment: @SJuan76 Considering *vents* allow you to *vent* the individual gasses wherever your *vents* lead, then yeah, I'd say it's pretty useful.

Comment: @user1027 - vents _both_ CO and O2?  Kinda makes you wonder if the totally interchangeable connectors on _all_ the hoses are really as good an idea as Mark thinks ...